# Loading javascript in a Dojo ContentPane

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am stuck again.  I am trying to load some javascript (a number spinner) into a Dojo content pane.  And I get a nice ugley message:

```
Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
```

Here is my code.  Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="isDebug: false, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="numberspinner.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="numberspinner.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var init = function()
{ dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
}
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>

</head>

<body class="tundra">


<div id="notworkingtab" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Location">

<script type="text/javascript">
var abc= new SpinControl();
abc.SetMaxValue(5);
abc.SetMinValue(0);
abc.SetCurrentValue(0);
abc.SetIncrement(0.5);
document.body.appendChild(abc.GetContainer());
abc.StartListening();
</script>

</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And if anyone cares, I got my numberspinner from here:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-controls-the-spin-control

It shows me the number spinner, but not the content pane, and I get the error above...  If I take the number spinner out the content pane works ok.  Or if I take the contentpane out, the number spinner works ok.

Thanks
gggggggg

Answer (score 4):

I think that the `dojox.layout.ContentPane` widget is what you are looking for.

`dojox.layout.ContentPane` is an extension to `dijit.layout.ContentPane` providing script execution, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the comment/answer I have for you is are you trying to do this "non" dojo like.  Basically by doing the things you are doing, you will end up with a very un-dojo like application.

If the native dijit or dojox controls don't provide the functionality you want, you would be better off wrapping your number spinner as a dijit Widget yourself.  You get a lot of advantages, like the `dijit.layout.ContentPane` "owning" the sub control and will automatically manage it, etc.  At first I thought creating custom Widgets would be daunting, but in the end, it isn't difficult at all.

Also, `dijit.layout.ContentPane` doesn't normally allow the running of JavaScript on load, since the parser ignores it.  You can use the `dojox.layout.ContentPane` to provide this functionality, but over time I have learned that usually what I want to do can be done via a `<script type="dojo/method">` or `<script type="dojo/connect">`.

Personally I think you will be much happier with the results long term.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I will take a look and see what i can learn.

Comment: +1 for the dojox.layout.ContentPane recommendtation. I skimmed over your answer earlier when I was looking for a solution, but must have missed it. Had a similar problem as the OP regarding contentPane not loading scripts etc. Using dojox.layout.ContentPane rather than dijit.layout.ContentPane worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I got it.. Blond moment.

document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(starrating.GetContainer());